# Htaccess ReWrite URL rule returning empty parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /asmi/

#---------package-details
RewriteRule ^package-details/(.*)/$ package-details.php?pckName=$1  
RewriteRule ^package-details/(.*)$ package-details.php?pckName=$1
```

My URL :

```
http://domain.com/asmi/package-details/Total-SMS-Alert/
```

I am not able to get $_REQUEST['pckName'].

Comment: You are looking for `$_GET['pckName']`.

Comment: Uncomment the `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: @ hjpotter92 : that is alos not working..

url structure is :
http://domain.com/asmi/

Comment: Is htaccess being loaded? Put some garbage in the file and see if the server throws a 500 error.

Comment: yes it is loaded.. htaccess works fine for below rule

#---------about-us
RewriteRule ^about-us/#(.*)/$ about-us.php#$1
RewriteRule ^about-us/#(.*)$ about-us.php#$1

Comment: @ hjpotter92 : 
i edited and written
RewriteRule ^package-details555/(.*)/$ package-details.php?pckName=$1 
RewriteRule ^package-details555/(.*)$ package-details.php?pckName=$1 

it should throw error.. but it is not throwing any error..
instead it is taking me to package-details.php page